# Excel AddIn installed and uninstall event

Tags: excel, vsto, excel-dna, xll

I am trying to load excel xll addin in Excel VSTO.

I used `Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns.Add` and `.Installed` to install and uninstall xll

```
            AddIn intelliSenseAddIn = default;
            if (intelliSenseAddInOption.Checked)
            {
                intelliSenseAddIn = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.AddIns.Add(@"xx.xll");
                intelliSenseAddIn.Installed = true;
            }
            else
            {
                intelliSenseAddIn.Installed = false;
            }
```

But, user can uncheck the addin from built-in tab, I am wondering whether there is any event will fire when user uncheck or check the item in Excel Addins windows

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there's an event in the COM object model for this, but when the user uninstalls the .xll add-in, the `IExcelAddIn.AutoClose` in the Excel-DNA add-in will be called.

Comment: Is `IExcelAddIn.AutoClose` fire only for  my own addin or it will fire when any addin uninstall?

Comment: @Edward It is an entry point in your own addin. Other addins that are uninstalled will process the AutoClose() call in their own way, but you don’t have a simple way to hook into that.